# How strict is undefined index?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, undefined-index

I've turned on all error reporting to clean up some undefined indexes, just to make the app I'm making more neat. I've noticed a curious behavior:

Let's say I have the following array: `$a = array('test' => false, 'foo' => 'bar')`

If I do `if ($a['nothere'])`, I properly get a notice of `Undefined index:  nothere`.

However, if I do `if ($a['test']['nothere'])`, I *don't* get a notice. At all. Despite `nothere` definitely not being an index in `$a['test']`.

Now, if I do `$a['test'] = array('baz' => 'poof')`, then running `if ($a['test']['nothere'])` *does* throw a notice.

Does undefined index checking not check for indexes in an empty array? This is on PHP 5.2.8.

Comment: it's most likely because [] string access syntax and type juggling. `$a = array('test' => array(), 'foo' => 'bar')` would produce you an error

Comment: hah, thanks for editing out the curious construction caused by a previous copyedit, @Piskvor. :P

Comment: Ah, so you're suggesting, when it does `if($a['test']['nothere'])`, it gets as far as `if($a['test'])`, sees that resolve to `false`, and short circuits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's because of tricky type juggling. 
$a['test'] being cast to [empty] string and then 'nowhere' being cast to 0 and then PHP tries to look for 0's symbol in the empty string. It becomes substring operation, not variable lookup, so, no error raised.

Gee, a man says the same: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

A curious example from my experience:
Being requested via hyperlink `index.php?sname=p_edit&page=0`, a code

```
if (isset($_GET['sname'])) { $page['current'] = $_GET['sname'].'.php'; };
echo $page['current'];
```

produces just one letter `"p"`

I counted 6 steps and 2 type casts which ends up with such a result.
(Hint: a poor fellow who asked this question had register globals on)

Comment: +1 allso you should use isset when you're checking for variables ( may them be array , strings whatever )